# JustHost Cpanel - MySQL username/password access remotely

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Not sure if this is the right forum for me to ask this question.

But I'm wondering does anyone having difficult using JustHost as web hosting provider in establishing remote access to their mysql database server environment?

What happened recently was that I'm trying to use mySQL ODBC driver connector via MS access to access their mysql database.

Originally I know what my username/password is and JustHost(well.. at least that's what I think they normally do) is set this similar setup for all other CPanel access such as your FTP, email, billing info, etc, etc.
Thus I tried using my username/password to logon into the mysql database via MS ACCESS's odbc connector.  But I kept on being rejected to log in.

I started whether the password I used to log on my CPanel services would be different that the one used to access mysql via PHPAdmin window.  Thus with that in mind, I forwarded the query to Justhost helpdeskteam.

Unfortunately they don't have a clue about this.

Thus that's what brought me here in this forum, begging this question - does anybody know what's the appropriate approach in remotely connecting mysql database environment via a web hosting provider such as Justhost.com?

Sorry for the elongated story.

Thought it would help to state the meaningfulness of my supposedly-trivial problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in to your JustHost account and scroll down to Remote MySQL. You need to add the IP address(es) of the remote server(s) to the list of Access Hosts.

Comment: I did that.  Here's the thing.  I don't use any external web server.  I'm trying to connect to mysql database server remotely from my laptop.  So I'm not sure what IP address am I supposed to provide for that field?

Comment: You can use the wildcard `%` alone which will allow access from anywhere. It's not optimal, but your database will be be (/should be) password-protected.

Comment: Yeah.  I did consider that.  Didn't like this option cause it pose as a security risk to me.  I'll give it a go and see what happens...

Comment: Hi.  It's all good now.  I found what's wrong it.  Your advice certainly helps after I found what's my actual external IP address I need to provide before I can have the remote mysql access. Thanks!